# Why is jQuery POSTing in UTF-16?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, utf-8

The blog post creation page of my blog software [LightBlog](http://code.google.com/p/lightblog) uses jQuery to POST the content via AJAX. Oddly enough, when I submit Chinese characters (中文) through jQuery, it sends it to the server in UTF-16. When I disable the jQuery AJAX and use Firefox to POST it, it sends it in UTF-8, like it should.

Checking in Firebug, jQuery sends this: `%u4E2D%u6587`, which is apparently URL-encoded UTF-16.
Firefox sends this: `%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87`, which is definitely URL-encoded UTF-8.

jQuery claims to POST in UTF-8 in accordance with W3 specs, so why is it sending in UTF-16?

The jQuery code in question:

```
$('#create').submit(function() {
    var inputs = [];
    $('.cf', this).each(function() {
        inputs.push(this.name + '=' + escape(this.value));
    })
    jQuery.ajax({
        data: inputs.join('&'),
        type: "POST",
        url: this.getAttribute('action'),
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        timeout: 2000,
        success: function(json) {
            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
            alert(r.result);
        }
    })
    return false;
})
```

The relevant PHP code, if anyone needs it, is in the first `if` condition in this file: http://code.google.com/p/lightblog/source/browse/trunk/Sources/ProcessAJAX.php?r=521

Comment: I believe it depends on the character set that's defined on the page itself (either via `header:` or `<meta http-equiv`); internally JS is utf-16

Comment: Looks like you spotted a bug with jQuery. Please report it in their bugtracker. I smell an incompatiblity with your browser. Otherwise I'd say if the request is json encoded, that this is still correct (not to the jquery docs but to the json/javascript specs).

Comment: Happens in IE9, Firefox 13, and Chrome 19 with jQuery 1.7.2. The request is correct, other than the UTF-16 encoding. Thanks, I'll report it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-16 is returned from `escape(this.value)`, it has nothing to do with jQuery.

Try running `escape("中文")` in a console.

You should use `encodeURIComponent()` which seems to generate string that you expect ("%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87"),

**or**

let jQuery do all encoding part by passing data as a hash, instead of a string.

**... or**

instead of creating a data manually, try using `$(".cf").serialize()` or `$(".cf").serializeArray()` to get the POST string/data array.

Comment: You're correct. I had a friend help me out and we came to the exact same conclusion about an hour ago. Thanks for the answer, though!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the content type to `UTF-8`.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: I've done that. Doesn't help. I've also tried setting it via PHP's header().